# SQL group related rows in a list

Tags: sql

I'm a bit stuck with this...

I have items table:

```
id | name
 1 | item 1
 2 | item 2
 3 | item 3
 4 | item 4
```

and related items table:

```
id | item_id | related_item_id
 2 |      1  | 2
 3 |      1  | 4
```

so this means that item 1 is related to items 2 and 4.
Now I'm trying to display these in a list where related items follow always the main item they are related to:

```
item 1
item 2
item 4
item 3
```

Then I can visually show that these items 2 and 4 are related to item one and draw something like:

```
item 1
-- item 2
-- item 4
item 3
```

To be honest, haven't got any ideas myself. I quess I could query for items which are not related to any other item and get a list of "parent items" and then query relations separately in a script loop. This is not definately the sexiest solution...

Comment: Can we assume that an item is related to only one other item?  (That is, the resulting list does not have any duplicate items.)  So, (1, 2) and (1, 4) is allowed, but not (2, 1) and (4, 1).

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Yes, resulting list doesn't have any duplicate items. I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that this question is about ordering the items list, without duplicates.  That is, a given item does not have more than one parent (which I ask in a comment).

If so, you can do this with a `left outer join` and cleverness in the `order by`.

```
select coalesce(r.related_item_id, i.id) as item_id
from items i left join
     related r
     on i.id = r.related_item_id
order by coalesce(r.item_id, i.id),
         (r.related_item_id is null) desc;
```

The `left outer join` identifies parents because they will not have any rows that match.  If so, the `coalesce()` finds them and uses the item id.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to do the trick for me... It really does order the list in a way where related items (subitems) follow parent item; but, these related subitems aren't always next to each other. There could be another item between these related subitems, because it's ID is bigger than first parent item ID and smaller than last subitem ID. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion , rather than implementing this logic in a query , you should move it to your actual code.
assuming that item_ids are sequential, you can find the largest number of item_id, then in a loop
you can find related_item_id to each item_id and make a convenient data structure out of it.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality comes under the category of hierarchical queries. In Oracle its handled by connect by  clause not sure about mysql. But you can search "hierarchical queries mysql" to get the answer.